Layouting with tested tikz graphs
I'm using the tree layout with tikz, which generally works very well, but sometimes, when using subgraphs, I end up with edges that are perfectly aligned on top of each other like this:

In my code below, I've also tried various other layout methods, like spring layout and the electric variants. But they similarly seem to have problems with nested layouts, and the forces don't propagate well through the levels. This results in a bunch of nodes lumped on top of each other.
Is there a trick I need to get layouts to with with nested layouts?
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing, quotes, arrows.meta}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
    every node/.style={
        font=\scriptsize,
        inner sep=2pt,
    },
    identity/.style={circle, draw=black, fill=white, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt},
    var/.style={circle, draw=black, fill=white, inner sep=2pt},
    function/.style={circle, draw=black, fill=white, inner sep=2pt},
    subgraph nodes={draw=gray, rounded corners},
    subgraph text none,
]
\graph [
    tree layout,
    grow'=right,
    fresh nodes,
    sibling sep=5em,
    node distance=1cm,
    node sep=1cm,
    nodes behind edges,
    nodes={align=center},
] {
    main+cluster [draw=black, circle] // [tree layout]{
        sub+cluster // [tree layout]{
            node+A[function,as=$A$];
            node+x1[var,as=$x$];
            (node+x1) -> [-latex, "$i$"] (node+A);
        },
        node+x2[var,as=$x$];
        (node+A) -- ["$i$"] (node+x2);
    },
    node+j[as=];
    (node+A) -- ["$j$"] (node+j);
    node+i+prime[as=];
    (main+cluster) -- [Circle-, "$i'$"] (node+i+prime);
};
\end{document}


Hello, I didn't understand what the problem is.

I'm sorry. In the picture, do you see the two (x) nodes? They both have an edge to the (A) node, but the edges are completely on top of each other, making it hard to read. One of the edges even pass through the other (x) node.

The problem (I think) come from nested layouts where [[A x] x] gets laid out in a straight horizontal line, rather than "splaying out" the way [A x x] would.

If I understand correctly, there are two possibilities in my opinion: to place the x on the right lower or to curve the arrow, or even to do both at the same time.

I agree. Maybe the confusion is this: I'm auto generating the tikz code, so I don't get to manually move the nodes around. I'm trying to get the graphdrawing library to do it for me. Mostly it does a good job, but sometimes it fails, like here.

Here's a proposal, I've moved the x node down with nudge down =5mm and bent the arrow with out=-80,in=230,looseness=1.4. You can change these settings to adjust this as closely as possible to your idea.
node+x2[var,nudge down=5mm,as=$x$];
(node+A) -- [out=-80,in=230,looseness=1.4,"$i$"] (node+x2);

The full code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing, quotes, arrows.meta}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
    every node/.style={
        font=\scriptsize,
        inner sep=2pt,
    },
    identity/.style={circle, draw=black, fill=white, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt},
    var/.style={circle, draw=black, fill=white, inner sep=2pt},
    function/.style={circle, draw=black, fill=white, inner sep=2pt},
    subgraph nodes={draw=gray, rounded corners},
    subgraph text none,
]
\graph [
    tree layout,
    grow'=right,
    fresh nodes,
    sibling sep=5em,
    node distance=1cm,
    node sep=1cm,
    nodes behind edges,
    nodes={align=center},
] {
    main+cluster [draw=black, circle] // [tree layout]{
        sub+cluster // [tree layout]{
            node+A[function,as=$A$];
            node+x1[var,as=$x$];
            (node+x1) -> [-latex, "$i$"] (node+A);
        },
        node+x2[var,nudge down=5mm,as=$x$];
        (node+A) -- [out=-80,in=230,looseness=1.4,"$i$"] (node+x2);
    },
    node+j[as=];
    (node+A) -- ["$j$"] (node+j);
    node+i+prime[as=];
    (main+cluster) -- [Circle-, "$i'$"] (node+i+prime);
};
\end{document}



Thank you Andre, this looks good; but as mentioned in the comments above, I need a general purpose solution, since I'm generating the tikz code programatically. I'm not able to go through each one and add nudges. I'm trying to solve the problem using the layout algorithms.

In this case, you need to specify the tool that allows you to generate this code. It is the one that needs to be programmed.

I'm using the graphdrawing library, it's supposed to lay out the nodes automatically. If you see https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs you'll notice there are no manual positioning done.

The graphdrawing library does not generate code automatically. To generate a tikz code automatically, it is necessary to use software external to Tikz. Some do it like Geogebra, for graphs, I don't know of any. Which one do you use?

I just use python to write the tikz code. But it shouldn't be important. The point is that graphdrawing automatically lay out the nodes without manual positioning. But it has an issue with subgraphs, and that's all I'm asking about.

Ah, I think I'm starting to get it. What I don't understand is why you need a subgraph in this case, a graph does the trick, right? And in case you need a subgraph, the options for it are currently the same as the main graph. If you want to change the orientation, it makes you change the orientation of the subgraph with e.g. grow'=down.

The subgraph is what allows me to draw the rectangle around A-x. I think subgraphs are a really cool feature in tikz that I haven't found in any other graph drawing library. There just seems to be some bug/issue with how they affect automatic layouting. I could do grow=down on the outer graph. Maybe I should switch between right and down at each level of the hierarchy. But it's kinda a hack rather than a real solution. So it might still break at times.

You can change the algorithm for the subgraph, for example, use spring layout, which will change the orientation of the nodes.

Right, I mentioned that in my question, but it seems it also doesn't work well with subgraphs. So I'm wondering if there's some trick in missing, or if this is just a known limitation of all graphdrawing algorithms

Which works great is to leave tree layout for the main graph and spring layout for the subgraphs.
